# Textures bug in the space below the page on Android devices

Tags: android, css, templates, browser, drupal

While testing our site on different devices we found a problem on recent Android versions. There is a bug with textures under the page, where the content ends (actually there is no any content where appears the bug). The bug appears only when the height of the page zoomed out is smaller then the screen of a device. Previous Android versions (4.1 etc) show there just white space (as Apple and Windows mobile devices also do), but 4.4 and later randomly repeats some portions of the site. We tried different viewport metatag options as well as different "height=100%" and "min-height=100%" tricks in CSS with no result. Any ideas on how we can fix it? Thanks.

Screenshot: http://i11.pixs.ru/storage/7/5/4/2jpg_2263155_16706754.jpg

Comment: have you tested it on actual device? emulators can not give you native rendering, since screenshot shows you are using virtual machine for mac on windows.

Comment: Yes, it is reproducible on real devices (both on phones and tablets). For example: http://i11.pixs.ru/storage/7/8/5/Screenshot_3828946_16706785.png